# SQL select tag for blog post

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm creating a blog and want to show tags for all my post. Each post can have many tag. So i stored tag information in a table called tblTag , and my blog post stored in tblPost.

Currently, to show all post and all tag per post. I'm using the below method:

```
Select * from tblPost // this to select all post
```

And do a while loop per blog post:

```
Select * from tblTag where BlogPostID= ... // this to select tag per post
```

This work. But the performance is very bad. I don't want the server to run a lot of query.
Anyway to do is better ?

Comment: Can you describe the structure (column's name) of `dbo.tblTag` ?

Comment: "Anyway to do this better". Do what? Get all posts along with their tags? You can use JOIN to get all that information in single query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT p.*, LEFT(ISNULL(t.n,''), LEN(t.n) - 1)
FROM tblPost p
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT it.TagName + ',' FROM tblTag it WHERE it.BlogPostId = p.BlogPostId FOR XML PATH('')) t(n)
WHERE p.BlogPostID = ...
```

This will give you all of the tags, separated by commas, in a separate column.

Comment: Is this able for SQL-server-2005 or SQL-server-2008 ?

Comment: @monocular Yes, it should work for both 2005 and 2008. But try running it in SSMS just to make sure...

Comment: @monocular If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as the answer by using the green checkmark...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL query to get the post information (title, date, etc), and also all tag rows associated with this post.

```
SELECT p.*, t.* FROM tblPost p
left join tblTag t on t.BlogPostID = p.id
```

Once you've got the above, you can cycle through the rows in your dataset.

Comment: But one post may have meny Tag. How to join meny tag row in one post row and separate by ","? For example : Post #1, tag: a,b,c